# Fixed background on Android doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I tryed almost everything but doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
html, body{ 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px; }

.banner {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url('http://wallpoper.com/images/00/31/33/51/black-background_00313351.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}


<div class="banner" id="bannera"></div>

<div class="l-content" style="height: 700px;"> </div>
```

[Try it: jsfiddle.net/6rf4o2aj/](http://jsfiddle.net/6rf4o2aj/)

Comment: you are saying that in android you can see the background on the whole Page?

Comment: no, I am just saying that background fixed doesn't work on the android devices. So on the android devices you see this: http://jsfiddle.net/6rf4o2aj/3/ instead of this: http://jsfiddle.net/6rf4o2aj/

Answer (score 0):

Apply the background to `body` instead of `banner`. http://jsfiddle.net/6rf4o2aj/2/

Comment: Just tried but it doens't work. And then I need to use many .banner in the page.